# How to retrieve data from Python IDLE manually

Tags: python, ide

During one of my IDLE sessions, I cut a text selection and mistakenly closed the IDLE and I lost the cut text. Is there a way to get this text back, perhaps, if I can get the path of its clipboard?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no method to do that but maybe view last restart shell option may help you.

Comment: Oh, Where can I get this option?

Comment: In shell menu in the shell window only, you get that option. I am still not sure whether this may help you.

Comment: I am sorry then, I will try out some other solutions and check if I they help.